# Abrir asp:panel visible = true desde un enlace en diferente archivo

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Saludos.
Tengo 3 paneles con `visible=false` y en el `.cs` el método que muestra uno o otro según el botón que se oprima, pero todo esto esta dentro del mismo archivo `products.aspx/.cs`. Que pasa si quiero ejecutar el `panel.visible = true` pero desde un enlace externo otro archivo diferente, por ejemplo desde `index.aspx`.

Adjunto dibujo haber si me hago entender mejor. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
protected void Button_ProductosClick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.PanProductsOne.Visible = true;
    this.PanProductsTwo.Visible = false;
    this.PanProductsThree.Visible = false;

}
protected void Button_ProductosClick_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.PanProductsOne.Visible = false;
        this.PanProductsTwo.Visible = true;
        this.PanProductsThree.Visible = false;

    }
protected void Button_ProductosClick_3(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.PanProductsOne.Visible = false;
        this.PanProductsTwo.Visible = false;
        this.PanProductsThree.Visible = true;

}
```

Comment: lo que se me ocurre, es que pases una sesión desde default.aspx, a products.aspx, y compares el valor que trae para hacer el código que deseas (obviamente por cada botón debes darle un valor distinto) adjuntaría un ejemplo y lo haría respuesta, pero no soy muy bueno en asp.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes pasar valores entre paginas por medio de un querystring:

En tus botones el redirect los harías así (dependiendo el botón es el valor de var):

`Response.Redirect("products.apsx?var=1");`

Y en tu pagina products.aspx, en el evento page_load, recuperas el valor así:

```
string strVar = request.querystring["var"];
```

Ya con el valor del query string, puedes usar un if o un switch para mostrar el panel que corresponde.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su tiempo compadre, y es muy posible que esto sea básico, pero no entendí correctamente, hice unas pruebas y no me resulta, intenté esto:  en el default.aspx
`protected void Button_ProductosClick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("http://192.168.48.26/contenido/productos.aspx?var=Button1_Click()");}`

Esto en el products.aspx
`string strVar = Request.QueryString["var"];`

Comment: Solucionado compa, @Victor Aparicio muchas gracias por las pistas.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado de la siguiente manera:

**[default.cs]**

```
protected void Button_ProductosClick_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Response.Redirect("http://192.168.48.26/contenido/productos.aspx?showview=tff");
    }
    protected void Button_ProductosClick_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Response.Redirect("http://192.168.48.26/contenido/productos.aspx?showview=ftf");
    }
    protected void Button_ProductosClick_3(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Response.Redirect("http://192.168.48.26/contenido/productos.aspx?showview=fft");
    }
```

**products.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strVar = Request.QueryString["showview"];
        if (strVar == "tff") 
        {
            this.PanProductsOne.Visible     = true;
            this.PanProductsTwo.Visible     = false;
            this.PanProductsThree.Visible   = false;
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Getposition", "<script>window.location='#PosA';</script>");
        }
        if (strVar == "ftf" ) {
            this.PanProductsOne.Visible     = false;
            this.PanProductsTwo.Visible     = true;
            this.PanProductsThree.Visible   = false;
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Getposition", "<script>window.location='#PosA';</script>");
        }
        if (strVar == "fft")
        {
            this.PanProductsOne.Visible     = false;
            this.PanProductsTwo.Visible     = false;
            this.PanProductsThree.Visible   = true;
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Getposition", "<script>window.location='#PosA';</script>");
        }


    }
```

Codifique en "tff" la variable que es (true false false) abreviado, y luego recogí el valor en el products.cs que si es == a "tff" entonces muestre y esconda los paneles necesarios segun el `if(){}`. Gracias a @Victor Aparicio por la pista de por donde era la cosa.

Comment: Deberias de aceptar su respuesta ya que es exactamente lo que el sugirio.